Is this how \frac is supposed to look?
Maybe it's just me, but the vertical space between the numerator and denominator and the horizontal - in the following looks odd to me. I think they should be closer together. Here is the output

And here is the code
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
\]
\end{document}

Thoughts?

your code errors.

This question is similar to: Why is latex typesetting my fractions with so much vertical space?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Mico. Thank you. The answer you provided in that post was informative and made me think about how things should look in general. However, I think there was a slight of hand in your answer in that you used \tfrac followed by \frac in the second instance. Had you used \tfrac for both fractions in the second part the problem of alignment you site goes away. Indeed, the result looks not too bad. That said, I don't want to toss out convention willy-nilly. I'll have to play with this a little to see how it plays out.

You're welcome. Incidentally, I would not call my placement-adjustment method a slight of hand. Rather, it was just an easy way to place the numerator and denominator terms really close to the fraction bar. Would you have been more impressed if I had used \raisebox instructions with positive and negative lengths, as @egreg did for the \frac{1}{n} term in the new answer?

Let me retract the slight-of-hand comment -- it was not meant in a mean way. But I must clarify. My objection was to your use of \ttfrac{\sigma}{\epsilon} \frac{ky}{lz} instead of \ttfrac{\sigma}{\epsilon} \ttfrac{ky}{lz} . The result with the second formulation doesn't have the alignment issue you found offensive.

More generally, nobody addressed my actual question -- do you not find the image I posted unappealing? I do. I think it looks odd to have the two parts of the fraction so far apart. If there's nothing to be done about it, c'est la vie, but it was worth the ask. I was given code for a far superior \bar{} by someone on this forum by asking if it could be done -- you never know.

For me it is absolutely fine. But maybe this is, because I prefer good typography for more than four decades. And indeed it seems, you are now asking for opinion or typography not for how to change something using TeX …

@TonyK \ttfrac{\sigma}{\epsilon}\ttfrac{ky}{lz} looks horrendous and has the same misalignment as shown here, just not in the same magnitude but quite noticeable.

Keep in mind that a big part of good typography is about consistency, and having the baseline of nominator and denominator for every fraction wiggle about to fit tight bounding boxes around the glyphs surely is not consistent. So to answer your question whether that looks bad: No, it doesn't.

The real problem is that if you ask whether this output looks bad, you will get no definitive answer since I am sure that not everybody will find this output (un)appealing. So, it is a matter of personal taste and as such not really suited as Q&A on this site.

Thanks to all who weighed in. My bad. I should have phrased the question differently. i could have edited it but it was clear from the comments that I am in the minority so it's best to leave it. Lesson learned.

You should always take context into consideration.

Do you still think the same?
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\bar{X} = \frac{p}{d}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
\\
\bar{X} = \frac{p}{d}\frac{\raisebox{-2.25pt}{$1$}}{\raisebox{2.5pt}[0pt]{$n$}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
\end{gather}

\end{document}

In the second case, I emulated the alignment you propose by raising or lowering the items.

Point taken. But see my response to Mico.
